# What is the xpath regex to extract this meta tag?

Tags: html, regex, xpath, import.io

What is the XPath or regex to extract the content of this meta tag?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content
```

Comment: That did the trick. Funny, I'm sure I had tried the before with no luck :)